# what is the command similar to command isolate in maple?

Tags: matlab

in maple there is a command called isolate.
but what is the command having similar function in matlab

Comment: What does the isolate function do in maple?

Answer (score 0):

solve is probably the closest thing to isolate. Maple and Matlab have different purposes, don't get caught up trying to force one to do the other's command.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [isolate](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=isolate) command in Maple reorganizes an equation to isolate a subexpression to the left side. Handling of symbolic equations in MATLAB is a little different, and there isn't really an equivalent MATLAB command to do this. To get similar behavior in MATLAB, I would first use [SUBS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/subs.html) to substitute a new variable for the expression of interest, then solve for the new variable using [SOLVE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/solve.html). For example:

```
>> eq = '4*x*sin(x) = 3';            %# A sample equation
>> solve(subs(eq,'sin(x)','y'),'y')  %# Replace 'sin(x)' with 'y' and
                                     %#   solve for 'y'
ans =

3/(4*x)                              %# y = sin(x) = 3/(4*x)
```